# Calculate percentage in case when statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query where I need to calculate a percentage based on a condition in the case when statement. I have added the percentage logic but still it is not working.

My Tables

**doctors**

```
select * from doctors;
 id |    doctor_name    | specialization |  phone_no   |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-------------------+----------------+-------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | Amanda S kerr     | Pediatrician   |  2403329748 | 2021-06-06 17:19:12.171267 | 2021-06-06 17:19:12.171267
  2 | Joslyn F Blaylock | Gynecologist   |  6126256999 | 2021-06-06 17:22:36.28629  | 2021-06-06 17:22:36.28629
  3 | Delia K Clauson   | Psychiatrist   | 80172790121 | 2021-06-06 17:22:36.310017 | 2021-06-06 17:22:36.310017
  4 | David B Jackson   | Dermatologist  |  8477022294 | 2021-06-06 17:22:36.320672 | 2021-06-06 17:22:36.320672
```

**bills**

```
select * from bills;
 id | patent_id | total_price | medicine_fee |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 |         1 |         550 |          400 | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.16373  | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.16373
  2 |         2 |         320 |          200 | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.195536 | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.195536
  3 |         3 |         720 |          600 | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.206543 | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.206543
  4 |         4 |        1300 |         1200 | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.228731 | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.228731
  5 |         5 |         210 |          120 | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.23976  | 2021-06-06 17:32:09.23976
```

**patients**

```
id |    patient_name     | patient_problem  |            patient_address            |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+---------------------+------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | Micheal l Hart      | Anxiety Disorder | 708 Dola Mine road Raleigh NC 27608   | 2021-06-06 17:28:07.968691 | 2021-06-06 17:28:07.968691
  2 | Jose R Hall         | Sore Throat      | 370 Coplin Avenue Phenoix Az 85017    | 2021-06-06 17:28:07.998416 | 2021-06-06 17:28:07.998416
  3 | Felicia E Plaisance | Common Cold      | 4068 stone Lane ridley park, PA 19078 | 2021-06-06 17:28:08.00939  | 2021-06-06 17:28:08.00939
  4 | Deborah M Bray      | Uterine fibroids | 4308 Kuhl Avenue Norcross, GA 30092   | 2021-06-06 17:28:08.021334 | 2021-06-06 17:28:08.021334
  5 | Charles V Pete      | rosacea          | 1860 Jody Road Philadelphia, PA 19301 | 2021-06-06 17:28:08.032129 | 2021-06-06 17:28:08.032129
```

**patient_doctors**

```
select * from patient_doctors;
 id | doctor_id | patient_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 |         1 |          2 | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.295453 | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.295453
  2 |         1 |          3 | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.318303 | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.318303
  3 |         3 |          1 | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.33816  | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.33816
  4 |         2 |          4 | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.581618 | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.581618
  5 |         4 |          5 | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.64391  | 2021-06-06 17:29:53.64391
(5 rows)
```

My Query

```
select 
      bills.id as bill_id, 
      doctor_name,
      patient_name,
      (case 
        when doctor_name like 'D%' then  bills.medicine_fee +( (50/100) * bills.medicine_fee )
        else bills.medicine_fee
        end) as new_medicine_fee,
      bills.total_price
    from doctors
    INNER JOIN patient_doctors
    ON doctors.id = patient_doctors.doctor_id
    INNER JOIN patients
    ON patients.id = patient_doctors.patient_id
    INNER JOIN bills
    ON bills.patent_id = patients.id;

 bill_id |    doctor_name    |    patient_name     | new_medicine_fee | total_price 
---------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------
       2 | Amanda S kerr     | Jose R Hall         |              200 |         320
       3 | Amanda S kerr     | Felicia E Plaisance |              600 |         720
       1 | Delia K Clauson   | Micheal l Hart      |              400 |         550
       4 | Joslyn F Blaylock | Deborah M Bray      |             1200 |        1300
       5 | David B Jackson   | Charles V Pete      |              120 |         210
(5 rows)
```

**Update**

```
select 
  bills.id as bill_id, 
  doctor_name,
  patient_name,
  medicine_fee,
  (case 
    when doctor_name like 'D%' then  bills.medicine_fee +( **ROUND(50.0/100)** * bills.medicine_fee )
    else bills.medicine_fee
    end) as consultation_fee,
  bills.total_price
from doctors
INNER JOIN patient_doctors
ON doctors.id = patient_doctors.doctor_id
INNER JOIN patients
ON patients.id = patient_doctors.patient_id
INNER JOIN bills
ON bills.patent_id = patients.id
order by bills.id;

bill_id |    doctor_name    |    patient_name     | medicine_fee | consultation_fee | total_price 
---------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+-------------
       1 | Delia K Clauson   | Micheal l Hart      |          400 |              800 |         550
       2 | Amanda S kerr     | Jose R Hall         |          200 |              200 |         320
       3 | Amanda S kerr     | Felicia E Plaisance |          600 |              600 |         720
       4 | Joslyn F Blaylock | Deborah M Bray      |         1200 |             1200 |        1300
       5 | David B Jackson   | Charles V Pete      |          120 |              240 |         210
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is the `50 / 100`.  This returns `0`.  Add a decimal point so the result is not an integer:

```
  (case when doctor_name like 'D%' then  bills.medicine_fee + ( (50.0/100) * bills.medicine_fee )
        else bills.medicine_fee
   end) as new_medicine_fee,
```

Comment: after applying your solution the medical fee is increased by 100% not 50%.

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari . . . There is no `ROUND()` in this answer.

Comment: Yeah but I need to round of to whole number.

Comment: (1) That is not part of your question.  (2) Round *after* the multiplication:  `ROUND( (50.0/100) * bills.medicine_fee )`.